# any method for udp streaming video to be played in HTML browser page

Tags: html, udp, video-streaming, webrtc

is there a node js module, method using flash, or anything that can allow a udp streaming video, located at an address like udp://(ipaddress):port to be played in an HTML page?

i mean there has to be SOME way to play a udp video on a web page right?

is this WebRTC API the best way to do it?

thanks

Comment: What is your use case for video streamed over udp? If you have an existing video you want to be streamed, using HTML video elements would be your best bet. If instead, the video is a live broadcast, you'll likely need to use WebRTC which does work over Udp but you'll a server component first.

Comment: it is a constantly streaming rendered video from a UDP address

Comment: most the webRTC examples I am finding are examples of streaming live video / audio from the computers webcam, but I am trying to stream just a video that is constantly playing from a UDP address like udp://(ipaddress).... any idea where i could find an example on this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing something like this as well. A video stream (coming from ffmpeg in my case) and being pushed out over http:// but I think you could use the same principle for udp

I found a project that uses nodejs as a server to pick up the http packets being sent from ffmpeg, put them on a websocket to the browser, and then there's client-side Javascript that decodes each individual frame. In this case it was h.264, and the performance seems tolerable for real-time video.

https://github.com/131/h264-live-player

Answer (score 0):

Flash supports UDP sockets - but you will run out of browsers supporting Flash.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-181c51321220efd9d1c-8000.html#WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-181c51321220efd9d1c-7ffe

So you can use Flash open an UDP socket, decode the video and render it.

WebRTC may use internally UDP but certainly won't enable you to open a bare socket.